# Clear selection in JQuery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a `Jquery DatePicker` control like so.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" CssClass="textEntry" MaxLength="12"
                                ClientIDMode="Static" onkeyup="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;" ValidationGroup="vTimeSlot"></asp:TextBox>
```

The script for the control is as follows

```
$("#<%= txtDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                    yearRange: '1901:2050',
                    //maxDate: new Date(),
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    showMonthAfterYear: true,
                    inline: true,
                    altField: "#<%= HiddenDate.ClientID%>",
                altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                    shouldsubmit = true;
                    javascript: __doPostBack('<%= txtDate.ClientID%>', '');
                },
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                    shouldsubmit = false;
                }
            });
```

Say for example, I have chosen some date. I want to clear that on click of a `button` from code behind.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.val('')` to assign empty value to textboxes:

```
$("#<%= txtDate.ClientID%>").val('');
```

from code behind:

```
txtDate.Text = ""; or txtDate.Text = string.Empty;
```

Comment: I tried `txtDate.Text = ""` but it retains the selected date

Comment: what about this `txtDate.text = string.Empty;`

Comment: I will try it and revert to you.

Comment: if possible, try to handle in button's client click and use: $('your selector').datepicker( "setDate", null) which will reset the selection.

Comment: That is the first approach when changing the value from client side.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: Thanks a bunch, it works - `string.empty` :)

Answer (score 1):

Set value empty to clear datepicker value by **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**

```
   $(button).on("click",function(){
    $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID%>").val('');
    });
```

Comment: button from code behind can you explain actrually what you want so it will helpfull for me to give correct answer